# Use different account Id on python AWS SDK create_export_task

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm setting up a Python script that simply triggers the execution of the export task on CloudWatch, to export a specific log group into an S3 bucket.

Assuming the script runs with an account ID `123abc`, I need the export task to run on log group that belongs to another account ID, for example `456def`.

When the export task is created I see an error message saying the user is not authorized to perform `CreateExportTask` on resource `arn:aws:logs:eu-central-1:123abc:log-group:...`; in other words, the export task is being created using the account ID of the user/script instead of the real account ID of the log group. Indeed I need to set up the `create_export_task` call to specify the proper account ID.
AWS documentation says that `logGroupName` parameter in `create_export_task` call expects the log group name and not the complete ARN.

How can I accomplish my target?

Thank you everyone for your support!

The following is the code that contains the create export task call:

```
response = logs.create_export_task(
    logGroupName=log_group_name, 
    fromTime=export_from_time,
    to=export_to_time,
    destination=bucketS3,
    destinationPrefix=log_group_name.strip("/")
)
```

Please note I'm not interested in cross account related to S3 bucket but instead on log group.